# Description for a page with colour HEX value

Tags: meta-tags

I have pictures which have a list of main colours used in it. And each colour is also a hyperlink to a page, with listings for all pictures that contain that colour:

```
example.com/color/336600
```

So that page would contain images with colour #336600.
The problem I have is describing that for humans.
Currently I am saying something like:

All pictures with #336600 colour.

And it also has the colour shown next to it as well, so it's a little bit easier to understand.
The problem is most people don't know what that colour is as it's a HEX value. Unless they look at the colour, which is kind of pointless having listed the HEX value.

What might be a good way to describe it to the user?

As well as having page titles (meta) and perhaps a meta description. Currently the page meta title shows as:

All pictures with colour #336600

This doesn't really mean anything to most people.

Comment: What colour range are we talking? All 16,777,216 RGB colours? Or are your images somewhat limited?

Comment: The range is unlimited, either I will have to match to closest colour or leave it at the hex value.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen several places that produce color names based on a color code.   Given that there are 16 million+ hex colors, it would be pretty hard to have unique names for each and every one.  Whatever you do will have to accept approximate values by matching them to the nearest name.

On StackOverflow: [Function that converts hex color values to an approximate color name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993970/function-that-converts-hex-color-values-to-an-approximate-color-name)

Open source Javascript library to name colors released under Creative Commons License 2.5: http://chir.ag/projects/ntc/

Comment: Ntc looks like something I could use. I'll try it and update. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for

http://htmlcolorcodes.com/color-names/

Comment: That looks very good, trouble is I have hex value only. Any pointers to client or server side convertor to dynamically convert?

Comment: Here is another similar link: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors.asp

Comment: Not every hex value has a colour name.  Unless you need all 16.7 million hex values to have a name, you might have to use the closest hex to the one you have.